# Bash Script to install PostgreSQL - Failing

Tags: sql, bash, postgresql, shell, debian

I built this deployment script which runs when my debian 6.0 server is deployed. I have shown it here before (this is a linode stackscript incase anyone else is wondering):

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Install PostgreSQL
#
# Copyright (c) 2010 Filip Wasilewski <en@ig.ma>.
#
# My ref: http://www.linode.com/?r=aadfce9845055011e00f0c6c9a5c01158c452deb

function postgresql_install {
    aptitude -y install postgresql postgresql-contrib postgresql-dev libpq-dev
}

function postgresql_create_user {
    # postgresql_create_user(username, password)
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "postgresql_create_user() requires username as the first argument"
        return 1;
    fi
    if [ -z "$2" ]; then
        echo "postgresql_create_user() requires a password as the second argument"
        return 1;
    fi

    echo "CREATE ROLE $1 WITH LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '$2';" | sudo -i -u postgres psql
}

function postgresql_create_database {
    # postgresql_create_database(dbname, owner)
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "postgresql_create_database() requires database name as the first argument"
        return 1;
    fi
    if [ -z "$2" ]; then
        echo "postgresql_create_database() requires an owner username as the second argument"
        return 1;
    fi

    sudo -i -u postgres createdb --owner=$2 $1
}

postgresql_install
postgresql_create_user(username, password)
postgresql_create_database(dbname, username)
```

I deployed my server with this script, which was built on top of Filip's version, but then when I try to see if postgresql is running by typing pg_ctl it says command not found.

Where I have I gone wrong on this? Since it deploys when the server runs I am not able to see where it is going wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that you have `psql` and `createdb` in your `PATH`? You really should be using full paths in this sort of script.

Comment: I dont actually know about "path". What would be my full path, pointing to my postgresql installation?

Comment: I'm not sure where they would be, try saying `which psql` on a machine that has it all properly installed and accessible.

Comment: I typed which psql on my machine but it doesnt say anything, I installed it with apt-get so it should be in the standard location.

Comment: That suggests that none of the PostgreSQL stuff is in your `PATH`. Try `locate psql` or check the package to see where it is installing things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people say it looks like you don't have the PostgreSQL bin directory on your path. In my experience on Ubuntu with PostgreSQL 9.1/9.2 on install from apt, the postgres user is created but it doesn't properly set up your environment, so `pg_ctl` and `initdb` etc are not on your `PATH`.

I can't see what PostgreSQL version you're using, but my 9.1 & 9.2 instances store the binaries in `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin`

Check that directory to see if it contains pg_ctl and other binaries. If it does,

try running:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin
```

and see if that allows you to run `pg_ctl`. If so, you'll need to execute that at login from `.bashrc` or similar